# limit of CDF involving right extreme

Tags: probability, limits

I am trying to prove that if F is a cdf with finite right extreme ($\tau < \infty $), then $G=F(\tau - 1/x) , x>0$ is a cdf on $(0,\infty)$. For one of the steps:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} F( \tau - 1/x)
$$
and this should be equal to zero. Intuitively $-1/x$ goes off to $-\infty$ so the limit should be $F(-\infty) =0$ but should I be making another step first? or does the jump make sense?

Comment: Two annoying typos: $x\to0$ instead of "$x\to-\infty$"; and $-1/x$ goes off to $-\infty$ instead of "$1/x$ goes off to $-\infty$".

Comment: @Did, thanks, fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof works just fine! Again if you want to be a bit more rigorous and supply intermediate arguments, you could add the following intermediate steps:

$$\lim_{x\searrow0}\frac{1}{x} = -\infty $$

Also because $\tau < \infty$, it follows:

$$\lim_{x\searrow0}\left(\tau-\frac{1}{x}\right) = -\infty $$

Also, for your final step, you are essentially using the right-continuity of $F$ (since $F$ is a distribution function).

Comment: does right continuity imply that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(\tau - 1/x) =F( \lim_{x \to -\infty} (\tau - 1/x) )$? Also do you mean limit to $-\infty$, not $0$ ?

Comment: Yes to your first question! For the second one, no! Sorry, I missed this mistake in your original question. Notice that you have defined $G$ for $x>0$ (other cases can be handled again via indicator functions) .If $x \to -\infty$, then $\tau - 1/x \to \tau$, while for $x\to0+$ you get  $\tau - 1/x \to -\infty$.

Comment: So just to clarify, G is definitely right continuous since F is right continuous?

Comment: yes take $x_0 >0$ and now to show right continuous you look at the limit from the right, i.e. you look at  $G$ as $x \searrow x_0$. Then $\frac{1}{x} \nearrow x_0$ (from the left) and then $\tau-\frac{1}{x} \searrow \tau - \frac{1}{x_0}$ (from the right) and now the right continuity of $F$ comes into play